# Why does my point light shader shows a strange behaviour, and how do I fix it?

Tags: opengl, shaders, glsl

I follow the well known tutorial about lighting and model importing using [Learn opengl](http://learnopengl.com), i copy paste the code from the site. The author claims that the shader works but when i compile the source code, i got strange behaviour.

The texture loading is done using this function:

```
GLint TextureFromFile(const char* path, string directory, bool gamma)
{
    //Generate texture ID and load texture data 
    string filename = string(path);
    filename = directory + '/' + filename;
    GLuint textureID;
    glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
    int width, height;
    unsigned char* image = SOIL_load_image(filename.c_str(), &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);
    // Assign texture to ID
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, gamma ? GL_SRGB : GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    // Parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    SOIL_free_image_data(image);
    return textureID;
}
```

When I only use ambient lighting from the fragment shader, the textures are shown as expected, but when the normal and light direction are used in shader, i got this strange image. My code asked ASSIMP to generate normals when it loads the model, but still getting this as results.

(The remaining files are below)

Here is the **vertex shader**:

```
// Vertex shader:
// ================
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 normal;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 texCoords;

out vec2 TexCoords;
out vec3 fragPosition;
out vec3 Normal;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0f);
    fragPosition = vec3(model * vec4(position, 1.0f));
    Normal = mat3(transpose(inverse(model))) * normal;
    TexCoords = texCoords;
}
```

And the **fragment shader**:

```
// Fragment shader:
// ================
#version 330 core
struct Material {
    sampler2D texture_diffuse1;
    sampler2D texture_specular1;
    float shininess;
}; 
/* Note: because we now use a material struct again you want to change your
mesh class to bind all the textures using material.texture_diffuseN instead of
texture_diffuseN. */

struct PointLight {
    vec3 position;

    float constant;
    float linear;
    float quadratic;

    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
};

#define NR_POINT_LIGHTS 2

in vec3 fragPosition;
in vec3 Normal;
in vec2 TexCoords;

out vec4 color;

uniform vec3 viewPos;
uniform PointLight pointLights[NR_POINT_LIGHTS];
uniform Material material;

// Function prototypes
vec3 CalcPointLight(PointLight light, Material mat, vec3 normal, vec3 fragPos, vec3 viewDir);

void main()
{    
    vec3 result;
    vec3 viewDir = normalize(viewPos - fragPosition);
    vec3 norm = normalize(Normal);

    for(int i = 0; i < NR_POINT_LIGHTS; i++)
        result += CalcPointLight(pointLights[i], material, norm, fragPosition, viewDir);

    color = vec4(result, 1.0f);
}


// Calculates the color when using a point light.
vec3 CalcPointLight(PointLight light, Material mat, vec3 normal, vec3 fragPos, vec3 viewDir)
{
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(light.position - fragPos);
    // Diffuse shading
    float diff = max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);
    // Specular shading
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, normal);
    float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), mat.shininess);
    // Attenuation
    float distance = length(light.position - fragPos);
    float attenuation = 1.0f / (light.constant + light.linear * distance + light.quadratic * (distance * distance));    
    // Combine results
    vec3 ambient = light.ambient * vec3(texture(mat.texture_diffuse1, TexCoords));
    vec3 diffuse = light.diffuse * diff * vec3(texture(mat.texture_diffuse1, TexCoords));
    vec3 specular = light.specular * spec * vec3(texture(mat.texture_specular1, TexCoords));
    ambient *= attenuation;
    diffuse *= attenuation;
    specular *= attenuation;
    return (ambient + diffuse + specular);
}
```

Here is **the c++ source code** (using assimp for model loading, SOIL for image loading, and glm for matrix calculations):

```
// Std. Includes
#include <string>

// GLEW
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>

// GLFW
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

// GL includes
#include "Shader.h"
#include "Camera.h"
#include "Model.h"

// GLM Mathemtics
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

// Other Libs
#include <SOIL.h>

// Properties
GLuint screenWidth = 800, screenHeight = 600;

// Function prototypes
void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode);
void scroll_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xoffset, double yoffset);
void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos);
void Do_Movement();

// Camera
Camera camera(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f));
bool keys[1024];
GLfloat lastX = 400, lastY = 300;
bool firstMouse = true;

GLfloat deltaTime = 0.0f;
GLfloat lastFrame = 0.0f;

// The MAIN function, from here we start our application and run the Game loop
int main()
{
    // Init GLFW
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, "LearnOpenGL", nullptr, nullptr); // Windowed
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // Set the required callback functions
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);
    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, mouse_callback);
    glfwSetScrollCallback(window, scroll_callback);

    // Options
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);

    // Initialize GLEW to setup the OpenGL Function pointers
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    // Define the viewport dimensions
    glViewport(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);

    // Setup some OpenGL options
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // Setup and compile our shaders
    Shader shader("../../../Path/To/Shaders/model_loading.vs", "../../../Path/To/Shaders/model_loading.frag");
    Shader lampShader("../../../Path/To/Shaders/lamp.vs", "../../../Path/To/Shaders/lamp.frag");

    // Load models
    Model ourModel("../../../Path/To/Nanosuit/nanosuit.obj");
    // Used a lamp object here. Find one yourself on the internet, or create your own one ;) (or be oldschool and set the VBO and VAO yourselves)
    Model lightBulb("../../../Path/To/Lamps/Bulb.obj"); 

    // Draw in wireframe
    //glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);

    // Point light positions
    glm::vec3 pointLightPositions[] = {
        glm::vec3(2.3f, -1.6f, -3.0f),
        glm::vec3(-1.7f, 0.9f, 1.0f)
    };

    // Game loop
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // Set frame time
        GLfloat currentFrame = glfwGetTime();
        deltaTime = currentFrame - lastFrame;
        lastFrame = currentFrame;

        // Check and call events
        glfwPollEvents();
        Do_Movement();

        // Clear the colorbuffer
        glClearColor(0.05f, 0.05f, 0.05f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        shader.Use();   // <-- Don't forget this one!
        // Transformation matrices
        glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(camera.Zoom, (float)screenWidth/(float)screenHeight, 0.1f, 100.0f);
        glm::mat4 view = camera.GetViewMatrix();
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "projection"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "view"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));

        // Set the lighting uniforms
        glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "viewPos"), camera.Position.x, camera.Position.y, camera.Position.z);
        // Point light 1
        glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "pointLights[0].position"), pointLightPositions[0].x, pointLightPositions[0].y, pointLightPositions[0].z);     
        glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "pointLights[0].ambient"), 0.05f, 0.05f, 0.05f);       
        glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "pointLights[0].diffuse"), 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); 
        glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "pointLights[0].specular"), 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "pointLights[0].constant"), 1.0f);
        glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "pointLights[0].linear"), 0.009);
        glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "pointLights[0].quadratic"), 0.0032);      
        // Point light 2
        glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "pointLights[1].position"), pointLightPositions[1].x, pointLightPositions[1].y, pointLightPositions[1].z);     
        glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "pointLights[1].ambient"), 0.05f, 0.05f, 0.05f);       
        glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "pointLights[1].diffuse"), 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); 
        glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "pointLights[1].specular"), 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "pointLights[1].constant"), 1.0f);
        glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "pointLights[1].linear"), 0.009);
        glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "pointLights[1].quadratic"), 0.0032);      

        // Draw the loaded model
        glm::mat4 model;
        model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(0.0f, -1.75f, 0.0f)); // Translate it down a bit so it's at the center of the scene
        model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f)); // It's a bit too big for our scene, so scale it down
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "model"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
        ourModel.Draw(shader);

        // Draw the lamps
        lampShader.Use();
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(lampShader.Program, "projection"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(lampShader.Program, "view"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
        for(GLuint i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            model = glm::mat4();
            model = glm::translate(model, pointLightPositions[i]);
            model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f)); // Downscale lamp object (a bit too large)
            glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(lampShader.Program, "model"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
            lightBulb.Draw(lampShader);
        }

        // Swap the buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

#pragma region "User input"

// Moves/alters the camera positions based on user input
void Do_Movement()
{
    // Camera controls
    if(keys[GLFW_KEY_W])
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(FORWARD, deltaTime);
    if(keys[GLFW_KEY_S])
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(BACKWARD, deltaTime);
    if(keys[GLFW_KEY_A])
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(LEFT, deltaTime);
    if(keys[GLFW_KEY_D])
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(RIGHT, deltaTime);
}

// Is called whenever a key is pressed/released via GLFW
void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode)
{
    if(key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);

    if(action == GLFW_PRESS)
        keys[key] = true;
    else if(action == GLFW_RELEASE)
        keys[key] = false;  
}

void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos)
{
    if(firstMouse)
    {
        lastX = xpos;
        lastY = ypos;
        firstMouse = false;
    }

    GLfloat xoffset = xpos - lastX;
    GLfloat yoffset = lastY - ypos; 

    lastX = xpos;
    lastY = ypos;

    camera.ProcessMouseMovement(xoffset, yoffset);
}   

void scroll_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xoffset, double yoffset)
{
    camera.ProcessMouseScroll(yoffset);
}

#pragma endregion
```

Here is the **camera.h header file**:

```
#pragma once

// Std. Includes
#include <vector>

// GL Includes
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>



// Defines several possible options for camera movement. Used as abstraction to stay away from window-system specific input methods
enum Camera_Movement {
    FORWARD,
    BACKWARD,
    LEFT,
    RIGHT
};

// Default camera values
const GLfloat YAW        = -90.0f;
const GLfloat PITCH      =  0.0f;
const GLfloat SPEED      =  3.0f;
const GLfloat SENSITIVTY =  0.25f;
const GLfloat ZOOM       =  45.0f;


// An abstract camera class that processes input and calculates the corresponding Euler Angles, Vectors and Matrices for use in OpenGL
class Camera
{
public:
    // Camera Attributes
    glm::vec3 Position;
    glm::vec3 Front;
    glm::vec3 Up;
    glm::vec3 Right;
    glm::vec3 WorldUp;
    // Euler Angles
    GLfloat Yaw;
    GLfloat Pitch;
    // Camera options
    GLfloat MovementSpeed;
    GLfloat MouseSensitivity;
    GLfloat Zoom;

    // Constructor with vectors
    Camera(glm::vec3 position = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3 up = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), GLfloat yaw = YAW, GLfloat pitch = PITCH) : Front(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f)), MovementSpeed(SPEED), MouseSensitivity(SENSITIVTY), Zoom(ZOOM)
    {
        this->Position = position;
        this->WorldUp = up;
        this->Yaw = yaw;
        this->Pitch = pitch;
        this->updateCameraVectors();
    }
    // Constructor with scalar values
    Camera(GLfloat posX, GLfloat posY, GLfloat posZ, GLfloat upX, GLfloat upY, GLfloat upZ, GLfloat yaw, GLfloat pitch) : Front(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f)), MovementSpeed(SPEED), MouseSensitivity(SENSITIVTY), Zoom(ZOOM)
    {
        this->Position = glm::vec3(posX, posY, posZ);
        this->WorldUp = glm::vec3(upX, upY, upZ);
        this->Yaw = yaw;
        this->Pitch = pitch;
        this->updateCameraVectors();
    }

    // Returns the view matrix calculated using Euler Angles and the LookAt Matrix
    glm::mat4 GetViewMatrix()
    {
        return glm::lookAt(this->Position, this->Position + this->Front, this->Up);
    }

    // Processes input received from any keyboard-like input system. Accepts input parameter in the form of camera defined ENUM (to abstract it from windowing systems)
    void ProcessKeyboard(Camera_Movement direction, GLfloat deltaTime)
    {
        GLfloat velocity = this->MovementSpeed * deltaTime;
        if (direction == FORWARD)
            this->Position += this->Front * velocity;
        if (direction == BACKWARD)
            this->Position -= this->Front * velocity;
        if (direction == LEFT)
            this->Position -= this->Right * velocity;
        if (direction == RIGHT)
            this->Position += this->Right * velocity;
    }

    // Processes input received from a mouse input system. Expects the offset value in both the x and y direction.
    void ProcessMouseMovement(GLfloat xoffset, GLfloat yoffset, GLboolean constrainPitch = true)
    {
        xoffset *= this->MouseSensitivity;
        yoffset *= this->MouseSensitivity;

        this->Yaw   += xoffset;
        this->Pitch += yoffset;

        // Make sure that when pitch is out of bounds, screen doesn't get flipped
        if (constrainPitch)
        {
            if (this->Pitch > 89.0f)
                this->Pitch = 89.0f;
            if (this->Pitch < -89.0f)
                this->Pitch = -89.0f;
        }

        // Update Front, Right and Up Vectors using the updated Euler angles
        this->updateCameraVectors();
    }

    // Processes input received from a mouse scroll-wheel event. Only requires input on the vertical wheel-axis
    void ProcessMouseScroll(GLfloat yoffset)
    {
        if (this->Zoom >= 1.0f && this->Zoom <= 45.0f)
            this->Zoom -= yoffset;
        if (this->Zoom <= 1.0f)
            this->Zoom = 1.0f;
        if (this->Zoom >= 45.0f)
            this->Zoom = 45.0f;
    }

private:
    // Calculates the front vector from the Camera's (updated) Euler Angles
    void updateCameraVectors()
    {
        // Calculate the new Front vector
        glm::vec3 front;
        front.x = cos(glm::radians(this->Yaw)) * cos(glm::radians(this->Pitch));
        front.y = sin(glm::radians(this->Pitch));
        front.z = sin(glm::radians(this->Yaw)) * cos(glm::radians(this->Pitch));
        this->Front = glm::normalize(front);
        // Also re-calculate the Right and Up vector
        this->Right = glm::normalize(glm::cross(this->Front, this->WorldUp));  // Normalize the vectors, because their length gets closer to 0 the more you look up or down which results in slower movement.
        this->Up    = glm::normalize(glm::cross(this->Right, this->Front));
    }
};
```

The ** filesystem.h **:

```
#ifndef FILESYSTEM_H
#define FILESYSTEM_H

#include <string>
//#include "root_directory.h" // This is a configuration file generated by CMake.


class FileSystem
{
private:
  typedef std::string (*Builder) (const std::string& path);

public:
  static std::string getPath(const std::string& path)
  {
    static std::string(*pathBuilder)(std::string const &) = getPathBuilder();
    return (*pathBuilder)(path);
  }
  //const char * logl_root = "H:/OpenGLDev/LearnOpenGL-master";
//static char * logl_root = "C:/Users/Michael/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/glGame/glGame";
private:
  static std::string const & getRoot()
  {
    /*static char const * envRoot = getenv("LOGL_ROOT_PATH");
    static char const * givenRoot = (envRoot != nullptr ? envRoot : logl_root);*/
    /*static char const * givenRoot =  logl_root;
    static std::string root = (givenRoot != nullptr ? givenRoot : "");
    return root;*/
      return std::string("C:/Users/Michael/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/glGame/glGame");
  }

  //static std::string(*foo (std::string const &)) getPathBuilder()
  static Builder getPathBuilder()
  {
    if (getRoot() != "")
      return &FileSystem::getPathRelativeRoot;
    else
      return &FileSystem::getPathRelativeBinary;
  }

  static std::string getPathRelativeRoot(const std::string& path)
  {
    return getRoot() + std::string("/") + path;
  }

  static std::string getPathRelativeBinary(const std::string& path)
  {
    return "../../../" + path;
  }


};

// FILESYSTEM_H
#endif
```

The ** mesh.h **:

```
#ifndef MESH_H
#define MESH_H
// Std. Includes
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
// GL Includes
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h> // Contains all the necessery OpenGL includes
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>


struct Vertex {
    // Position
    glm::vec3 Position;
    // Normal
    glm::vec3 Normal;
    // TexCoords
    glm::vec2 TexCoords;
    // Tangent
    glm::vec3 Tangent;
    // Bitangent
    glm::vec3 Bitangent;
};

struct Texture {
    GLuint id;
    string type;
    aiString path;
};

class Mesh {
public:
    /*  Mesh Data  */
    vector<Vertex> vertices;
    vector<GLuint> indices;
    vector<Texture> textures;
    GLuint VAO;

    /*  Functions  */
    // Constructor
    Mesh(vector<Vertex> vertices, vector<GLuint> indices, vector<Texture> textures)
    {
        this->vertices = vertices;
        this->indices = indices;
        this->textures = textures;

        // Now that we have all the required data, set the vertex buffers and its attribute pointers.
        this->setupMesh();
    }

    // Render the mesh
    void Draw(Shader shader)
    {
        // Bind appropriate textures
        GLuint diffuseNr = 1;
        GLuint specularNr = 1;
        GLuint normalNr = 1;
        GLuint heightNr = 1;
        for(GLuint i = 0; i < this->textures.size(); i++)
        {
            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + i); // Active proper texture unit before binding
            // Retrieve texture number (the N in diffuse_textureN)
            stringstream ss;
            string number;
            string name = this->textures[i].type;
            if(name == "material.texture_diffuse")
                ss << diffuseNr++; // Transfer GLuint to stream
            else if(name == "material.texture_specular")
                ss << specularNr++; // Transfer GLuint to stream
            else if(name == "material.texture_normal")
                ss << normalNr++; // Transfer GLuint to stream
             else if(name == "material.texture_height")
                ss << heightNr++; // Transfer GLuint to stream
            number = ss.str();
            // Now set the sampler to the correct texture unit
            glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, (name + number).c_str()), i);
            // And finally bind the texture
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->textures[i].id);
        }

        // Draw mesh
        glBindVertexArray(this->VAO);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, this->indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        // Always good practice to set everything back to defaults once configured.
        this->unbindTextures();
    }

private:
    /*  Render data  */
    GLuint VBO, EBO;

    /*  Functions    */
    // Initializes all the buffer objects/arrays
    void setupMesh()
    {
        // Create buffers/arrays
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &this->VAO);
        glGenBuffers(1, &this->VBO);
        glGenBuffers(1, &this->EBO);

        glBindVertexArray(this->VAO);
        // Load data into vertex buffers
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->VBO);
        // A great thing about structs is that their memory layout is sequential for all its items.
        // The effect is that we can simply pass a pointer to the struct and it translates perfectly to a glm::vec3/2 array which
        // again translates to 3/2 floats which translates to a byte array.
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->vertices.size() * sizeof(Vertex), &this->vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->EBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->indices.size() * sizeof(GLuint), &this->indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        // Set the vertex attribute pointers
        // Vertex Positions
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*)0);
        // Vertex Normals
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*)offsetof(Vertex, Normal));
        // Vertex Texture Coords
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*)offsetof(Vertex, TexCoords));
        // Vertex Tangent
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
        glVertexAttribPointer(3, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*)offsetof(Vertex, Tangent));
        // Vertex Bitangent
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(4);
        glVertexAttribPointer(4, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*)offsetof(Vertex, Bitangent));

        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

    void unbindTextures()
    {
        for (GLuint i = 0; i < this->textures.size(); i++)
        {
            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + i);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        }
    }
};

#endif
```

And the image below is **the supposed image** shown when it runs:
[image]

**EDIT3:** This is **the image i got** (just changed the background color to white), now my point light directions and the triangle normals are working fine but still getting bug on my final fragment color:
[image]

And below are the image i get when i deactivate the "spec" and "attenuation" values into fragment color calculations (the diffuse and specular texture seems to be loaded succesfully, but their modifier **spec** and **attenuation** seems to cause the bug):
[image]

I'm nearly sure that **the bug is in fragment shader** but i don't know how i should modify it so that it works as claimed by the author of the tutorial.

I'm not an expert of GLSL, i'm just learning. Please help

Comment: okay i'm updating the question, seems that my post has a limit of 30000 chars :(, i'm going to upload the remaining files

Comment: How do you load your textures? This seems a bit like corrupted or nonexistent textures when reading them in the shader.

Comment: I updated the post, the remaining header files are there. Those files are not big files, the texture loading is in Mesh.h and Model.h files.

Comment: You're asking strangers to pour over & debug a whole lot of code here. A considerate first step would be to see whether you can reproduce the problem in a fresh project, with minimal steps — this helps narrow down where the problem might be occurring. For example, you can try chopping out all the user input & zooming code, if the problem occurs without pressing any buttons. The more you pare away, the easier it'll be to find the error in what's left.

Comment: @DMGregory, when I only use ambient lighting from the fragment shader, the textures are shown as expected, but when the normal and light direction are used in shader, i got this strange image. My code asked ASSIMP to generate normals when it loads the model, but still getting this as results

Comment: Don't tell me in a comment, edit the question to slim down the example. If the diffuse texture and ambient light components don't trigger the problem, take them out until you have the smallest piece of code that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Please check for OpenGL errors when using OpenGL functions, and output them to error logs.  Then use breakpoints to see if any set values are not set properly, namely uniform locations, and texture ids.  This does look like your textures are not being loaded or sent to the shader properly.  Or you are linking the wrong texture id.

Comment: What happens when you take the texture out from the calculations? Just output the light, not the texture color. It's a common debugging technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started with the same tutorials. None of them ever seem to work properly to be honest, I think that is intentional.

This is my oldest/simplest backup - I do more in here but you can use it as a template. The c++ code won't help you because it is not doing the same things the same way you are but once you get the hang of it that part should be easy.

vertex:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 normal;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 texCoord;
layout (location = 3) in mat4 model;

out vec2 TexCoord;
out vec3 FragPos;  
out vec3 Normal;
out vec3 VertexPosition;

    uniform mat4 view;
    uniform mat4 projection;

    void main()
    {
        gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0f);
        TexCoord = vec2(texCoord.x, 1.0 - texCoord.y);
        FragPos = vec3(model * vec4(position, 1.0f));
        Normal = mat3(transpose(inverse(model))) * normal;
        VertexPosition = (view*model*vec4(position, 1.0)).xyz; 
    }
```

frag:

```
#version 330 core

    struct DirectionalLight {
        vec3 direction;
        vec3 ambient;
        vec3 diffuse;
        vec3 specular;

    };

    struct PointLight {
        vec3 position;
        vec3 ambient;
        vec3 diffuse;
        vec3 specular;
        float constant; 
        float linear;   
        float quadratic;    
    };

    struct Material {
        sampler2D diffuseMap;    
        sampler2D specularMap;    
        sampler2D normalMap;    
        float shininess;
    }; 

    in vec2 TexCoord;
    in vec3 FragPos;  
    in vec3 Normal;
    in vec3 VertexPosition;


    out vec4 color;


    uniform vec3 viewPos;
    uniform DirectionalLight directionalLight;
    uniform PointLight light;
    uniform Material material;

    vec3 CalcDirLight(DirectionalLight dl, vec3 normal, vec3 viewDir, vec3 objectColor, vec3 specularColor);
    vec3 CalcPointLight(PointLight l, vec3 normal, vec3 viewDir, vec3 objectColor, vec3 specularColor);
    mat3 cotangentFrame(vec3 N, vec3 p, vec2 uv);
    vec3 applyNormalMap(vec3 N, vec3 V, vec2 texcoord);

    void main()
    {
        //vec4 objectColor = mix(texture(ourTexture1, TexCoord), texture(ourTexture2, TexCoord), 0.2);
        vec3 objectColor =  texture(material.diffuseMap, TexCoord).xyz;
        vec3 specularColor = texture(material.specularMap, TexCoord).xzy;


        vec3 vertexToEye = normalize(-VertexPosition);


        vec3 norm = normalize(applyNormalMap(Normal, vertexToEye, TexCoord));

        vec3 viewDir = normalize(viewPos - FragPos);

        vec3 result = CalcDirLight(directionalLight, norm, viewDir, objectColor, specularColor);
        result+=CalcPointLight(light, norm, viewDir, objectColor, specularColor);

        color = vec4(result, 1.0f);

    }

    vec3 CalcDirLight(DirectionalLight dl, vec3 normal, vec3 viewDir, vec3 objectColor, vec3 specularColor)
    {
        vec3 ambient = dl.ambient * objectColor;

        float diff = max(dot(normal, dl.direction), 0.0);
        vec3 diffuse = dl.diffuse * (diff * objectColor);

        vec3 halfwayDir = normalize(dl.direction + viewDir);
        float spec = pow(max(dot(normal, halfwayDir), 0.0), material.shininess);
        vec3 specular = dl.specular * (spec * specularColor);

        return (ambient + diffuse + specular);
    }

    vec3 CalcPointLight(PointLight l, vec3 normal, vec3 viewDir, vec3 objectColor, vec3 specularColor)
    {
        vec3 lightDir = normalize(l.position - FragPos);

        float distance    = length(l.position - FragPos);
        float attenuation = 1.0f / (l.constant + l.linear * distance + l.quadratic * (distance * distance)); 

        vec3 ambient = l.ambient * objectColor * attenuation;

        float diff = max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);
        vec3 diffuse = l.diffuse * (diff * objectColor) * attenuation;

        vec3 halfwayDir = normalize(lightDir + viewDir);
        float spec = pow(max(dot(normal, halfwayDir), 0.0), material.shininess) * attenuation;
        vec3 specular = l.specular * (spec * specularColor);

        return (ambient + diffuse + specular);
    }

    mat3 cotangentFrame(vec3 N, vec3 p, vec2 uv)
    {
        // get edge vectors of the pixel triangle
        vec3 dp1 = dFdx(p);
        vec3 dp2 = dFdy(p);
        vec2 duv1 = dFdx(uv);
        vec2 duv2 = dFdy(uv);

        // solve the linear system
        vec3 dp2perp = cross(dp2, N);
        vec3 dp1perp = cross(N, dp1);
        vec3 T = dp2perp * duv1.x + dp1perp * duv2.x;
        vec3 B = dp2perp * duv1.y + dp1perp * duv2.y;

        // construct a scale-invariant frame 
        float invmax = inversesqrt( max( dot(T,T), dot(B,B) ) );
        return mat3( T * invmax, B * invmax, N );
    }

    vec3 applyNormalMap(vec3 N, vec3 V, vec2 texcoord)
    {
        // assume N, the interpolated vertex normal and 
        // V, the view vector (vertex to eye)
        vec3 map = texture2D( material.normalMap, texcoord ).xyz;
        //#ifdef WITH_NORMALMAP_UNSIGNED
            map = map * 255./127. - 128./127.;
        //#endif
        //#ifdef WITH_NORMALMAP_2CHANNEL
        //  map.z = sqrt( 1. - dot( map.xy, map.xy ) );
        //#endif
        //#ifdef WITH_NORMALMAP_GREEN_UP
        //  map.y = -map.y;
        //#endif
        mat3 TBN = cotangentFrame( N, -V, texcoord );
        return normalize( TBN * map );
    }
```

I recommend that you implement the tutorial to see where your normals are. From the results it seems your resulting normals are a big mess either from normal maps or else from bad lighting algorithm.

I dislike the way he does normals in that tutorial, instead I implemented this other way, which does not completely destroy your normal data so it's simple to debug and understand.

Sorry I do't have a one line fix but hopefully this helps. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

**Fragment Shader**

```
struct Material {
    sampler2D texture_diffuse1;
    sampler2D texture_specular1;
    float shininess;
};
```

Does not match:

**Mesh.h**

```
string number;
string name = this->textures[i].type;
if(name == "texture_diffuse")
    ss << diffuseNr++; // Transfer GLuint to stream
else if(name == "material.texture_specular")
    ss << specularNr++; // Transfer GLuint to stream
else if(name == "material.texture_normal")
    ss << normalNr++; // Transfer GLuint to stream
else if(name == "material.texture_height")
    ss << heightNr++; // Transfer GLuint to stream
```

Your names have to match your shader names.

**Fixed Mesh.h**

```
string number;
string name = this->textures[i].type;
if(name == "material.texture_diffuse")
    ss << diffuseNr++; // Transfer GLuint to stream
else if(name == "material.texture_specular")
    ss << specularNr++; // Transfer GLuint to stream
else if(name == "material.texture_normal")
    ss << normalNr++; // Transfer GLuint to stream
else if(name == "material.texture_height")
    ss << heightNr++; // Transfer GLuint to stream
```

Comment: The "ss << diffuseNr++;" line already puts the missing "1" to the "string name"

Comment: Oops my bad, but you are still missing the `material.` in front of the `texture_diffuse`.  Edited answer to remove the `1`s.